# Composition of polynomials over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, polynomials, finite-fields

Consider the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ over a finite field $k_q$ with $q$ elements where $q$ is prime:
$$
P_{n,q} = \left\{ x + c_2 x^2 + \cdots + c_n x^n:\ c_i \in k_q \right\}.
$$
It turns out that this set forms a group under composition of polynomials modulo $x^{n+1}$. Could you please tell, is it something well-known, and if it is so, could you please provide any references?

Comment: So if $\;p(x)=x^n\;,\;\;q(x)=x^2\;$ , then $\;p\circ g(x)=p(g(x))=p(x^2)=x^{2n}=x^{n-1}\pmod{x^n}\;$ , say?

Comment: This is known, e.g. the Nottingham group http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nottingham_group on power series.

Comment: @ahulpke The Nottingham group is, as you say, on (infinite, for sure) *power series*. Being a pro-$p\;$ group it is infinite, whereas the group of this question is finite.

Comment: @ahulpke Indeed, the group is finite, but still thank you for at least some reference.

Comment: The power series of the form $x+\sum_{j>n}c_jx^j$ form a normal subgroup, call it $H_n$, of the Nottingham group $N(k_q)$. What you have is the quotient $N(k_q)/H_n$.